# Return values from arraylist to an ajax success function

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets, arraylist

Retrieve data from an arraylist in the ajax success function. I need to populate my textfields latitude and longitude fields based on the ID passed via ajax. Everything works fine but the data is not rendered to the text fields. The success function returns nothing if the below code is executed. What is wroong in my code?

FetchData.class

```
public static ArrayList<Info> getAllInfo(String data_id) {
connection = FetchData.getConnection();
ArrayList<Info> inf = new ArrayList<Info>();
try {
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from info_table where data_id='"+data_id"'");

    while(rs.next()) {  
        Info in=new Info();
        in.setData_id(rs.getString("data_id"));
        in.setLat(rs.getDouble("Lat"));
        in.setLongi(rs.getDouble("Longi"));
        inf.add(in);
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return inf;
  }
}
```

Servlet class

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
 String dataID=request.getParameter("data_id");
ArrayList<Info> in=new ArrayList<Info>();
in=FetchData.getAllInfo();
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(in, new TypeToken<List<Info>>() {}.getType());

JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);

}
```

my ajax

```
$.ajax({
url:'Servleturl?dataID='document.getElementById("#data_id").value;
type:'GET',
dataType:'json',
success:function(data){
$("#lat").val(data.Lat);
$("#longi").val(data.Longi);
}
});
});
```

index.jsp

```
<input type="text" id="data_id" onblur=""/>
<input type="text" id="lat"/>
<input type="text" id="longi"/>
```

Comment: Any error on firebug console? And you see that request can be sent on network tab of firebug?

Comment: Sir no errors and on the console its printingg the values fine. Its just not retrieving in the success function.

Comment: Then, your ajax request is not functioning well. Check Network tab of firebug. What are you getting on ajax request

Comment: I am getting as undefined sir. data is not returning any value

Comment: Could you please go to `..../Servleturl?dataID=some_value` on your web browser? `some_value` needs to be available value. I want to know exact output of your controller request

Comment: Try adding `printOut.flush();` after printing your jsonArray

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for all the responses.

I finally found a solution to my own question. hope it will be useful for someone else.

I did the following code.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'Servleturl?dataID='document.getElementById("#data_id").value;
    type:'GET',
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(data) {
        document.getElementById("#lat").value=data[0].Lat;
        document.getElementById("#longi").value=data[0].Longi;
    }
});
```

As the data is returned from a arraylist should give the data as array itself to retrieve the values..

Thank  you all for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

put input field value
`<input type="text" id="data_id" onblur=""/>`
`<input type="text" id="lat" value=""/>`
`

`

Comment: It is not returning any values first of all sir.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `jsonArray.toString()`. If you don't want to use that you need to put extra code;

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String dataID=request.getParameter("data_id");
    ArrayList<Info> in=new ArrayList<Info>();
    in=FetchData.getAllInfo();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(in, new TypeToken<List<Info>>() {}.getType());

    response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter printOut = response.getWriter();

    JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
    printOut.print(jsonArray);
    printout.flush();
    // Or
    // printOut.print(jsonArray.toString())

}
```